# The get () function not working on laravel 8 updated version

Tags: php, laravel

This is the ArticlesController code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::latest()->get();
    return view('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles]);
}

public function show($id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);
    return view('articles.show', ['article' => $article]);
}

}
```

And this is the web.php code

```
Route::get('/articles', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@index');
```

and this is the layout.blade.php code

```
<li class={{Request::path() === 'articles' ? 'current_page_item' : ''}}><a href="/articles"
                                                                                       
accesskey="4"
```

[image: Here is the tree of the project]

[image: This is the main error page]

I tried so many different ways and it's working but in laravel 8 it's not.

Comment: did you define a method named `latest` on your model?

Comment: yes, and you can see it on the error pic too.

Comment: show this method named `latest` that you created, as that method is already defined on Eloquent Builder ...  we couldn't know what you are doing in the methods you create

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::query()->latest()->get();
    return view('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles]);
}
```